# Recursive groups in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR4 and I'm having a difficult time with its grammar.
Given you have data structured using the following rules:

- A message is a multiline collection of groups
- A group consist of a segment and possibly modifiers
- a segment is a three char alphanumeric
- a [ modifier indicates an optional group which (the group) is bounded by ]
- a { modifier indicates a repetition group which (the group) is bounded by }

An example of this data format is:

```
MSH
MSA
[{ ERR }]
[{ NTE }]
[
    [
        PID
        [{NTE}]
    ]
    {
        ORC
        [
             {
                  [TQ1]
                  [{ TQ2 }]
             }
        ]
    //shortened for brevity
    }
]
```

So that reads as:

- A required and singular MSH segment
- A required and singular MSA segment
- An optional group consisting of an optional group of PID and optional repeating NTE and a repeating group of ORC with an optional repeating optional TQ1 and optional repeating TQ2
- And so on...

So far I have:

```
message : group+ NEWLINE ;

group : ID+
      | (ID | '{'group'}'
      | (ID | '['group']'
      ;

OPTSTART : '[' ;
OPTEND : ']' ;
REPSTART : '{' ;
REPEND : '}' ;
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9]*
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I'm just stuck right now. I've managed to get the Parse Tree to parse the MSH and MSA but I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track. I would be very grateful for any pointers or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given description of the DSL:

> - A message is a multiline collection of groups
> - A group consist of a segment and possibly modifiers
> - a segment is a three char alphanumeric
> - a [ modifier indicates an optional group which (the group) is bounded by ]
> - a { modifier indicates a repetition group which (the group) is bounded by }

can be directly translated to an ANTLR grammar:

```
// each group self-terminates, so no NL terminal required
// use EOF terminal to ensure that entire source is parsed
message : group+ EOF ;

// list each possible representation of a group
group   : LBRACK group RBRACK
        | LBRACE group RBRACE
        | SEGMENT 
        ;

// literal implementation of a segment
SEGMENT : Char Char Char ;

// define literals only once
LBRACK  : '[' ;
RBRACK  : ']' ;
LBRACE  : '{' ;
RBRACE  : '}' ;

// all whitespace is inconsequential
WS      : [ \t\r\n]  -> skip ;

fragment Char : [a-zA-Z0-9] ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give this a try. When you say they ‘self terminate’ does that mean it terminates at then end of an alphanumeric series of char or if it’s a ] or }? I think I’m thinking of tokenizing like splitting a string using a delimiter and that’s probably the wrong way to think. Thanks

Comment: Self-terminate in the sense that each of the `group` alts are complete and require nothing further to signal that a particular group has ended.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help!